# How to delete all files which have certain name?

Tags: rm, delete

I need to delete all files which have certain name, at once and using the terminal.

All their name starts with `in.lsp`.

What is the command to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rm -f in.lsp*
```

Another answer would be:

```
find . -name 'in.lsp*' -exec rm {} \;
```

This second version gives you a little more power.   It lets you search directories other than `.`, it lets you choose to filter `-type d` or `-type f`, it lets you choose whether to remove files-only (`rm {}`) or files and directories (`rm -r {}`), etc.  It lets you choose on whether to follow symbolic links, to choose a search depth, search through regex, size, permissions, context, etc.

```
find . -name 'in.lsp*' -delete
```

can also work.

Comment: You might want to use the find command without the rm, just to confirm all the files you find are the ones you want to delete. Then rerun with the rm.